# How can I unlock the "That's More Like It" achievement?

Tags: dust-an-elysian-tail

In order to obtain the That's More Like It achievement ([link](http://www.xbox360achievements.org/game/dust-an-elysian-tail/achievement/69501-That-s-More-Like-It.html)), you need to execute a 1000+ hit combo, but I've never gotten anywhere even close to that. **How can I get my combo counter up to the 1000 mark?**

Note: I'm not very far into the game yet, does this become easier the further you progress?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Fairly early on in the game, you will run into 2 large rock monsters. You can fire your projectile by pressing B, and then combine it with an aerial dust storm by jumping and then holding Y. This fires numerous projectiles, and if you keep doing this by jumping back and forth, you can gain the achievement in short order. Check out this video to see the strategy in action:

You can also check out [this forum thread](http://www.xbox360achievements.org/forum/showthread.php?t=383757) for an additional video as well as some more tips on how to get this achievement.

Answer (score 4):

Three things need to be satisfied to achieve a 1000 hit combo:

- You need to make a lot of hits quickly without any combo-breaking gap between them.
- You need to not get hit while doing so.
- You need to not run out of enemies to hit.

Quickly making hits is most easily achieved by combining Fidget's standard Energy Blast projectile with Dust Storm, in order to produce a lot of projectiles that make a lot of hits, the Dust Storm itself can also rack up some hits quickly if aimed at enemies, but using it simply to enhance projectiles is quite acceptable. The energy used for Fidget's projectiles is replenished by hitting enemies with normal attacks, so mixing in some of those may be required.

Not getting hit is easiest against the basic melee enemy types, so finding a place where there are no other types of enemies is ideal.

In order to not run out of enemies the combined hit points of the group of enemies should be larger than 1000 times your average damage per hit. The first enemies you encounter in Sorrowing Meadow is a long stretch of zombies only, they are late-game enough to have a lot of hit points, but are otherwise very easy to deal with, so they are ideal. The supply of enemies can be stretched by reducing your own attack and fidget stats through unequipping equipment, and if that is not enough an [Ugly Pendant](http://elysiantail.wikia.com/wiki/Ugly_Pendant) can be used to make your attacks very weak. This trick is also useful for keeping enemies alive when "flying" by attacking airborne enemies.

These are just what I conceive to be the ideal conditions for making a 1000 hit combo, lots of different places can be used. Some might swear to a slightly different approach, and that may work fine as well.

Answer (score 2):

An easy solution, that works anywhere in the game is to unequip all your attack boosting and fidget boosting items and then equip the [Ugly Pendant](http://elysiantail.wikia.com/wiki/Ugly_Pendant). This pendant divides your attack, defense and Fidget's attack by ten, making it extremely easy to get a 1000 combo.

I think the description of the Ugly Pendant is a reference to this achievement (emphasis mine):

> This will actually make you weaker. **Why would anyone want to
>   intentionally do that?**

I managed to get the combo in the Sorrowing Meadow. This is a good location as there are a lot of enemies and the [Necromancers](http://elysiantail.wikia.com/wiki/Necromancers) will keep summoning more.

Answer (score 1):

I found a location near the end of the game that worked well even after I had beaten the final boss. (Spoilers for the description of the room.)

> In the final level, I went to the room where the invisible assassins killed the Moonblood sentry. By getting about four of them to attack me at once (which was very easy to do), I was able to spam Fidget's first projectile on them and make the combo.

Like eBusiness suggests, I equipped the [Ugly Pendant](http://elysiantail.wikia.com/wiki/Ugly_Pendant) to reduce my attack power. I also equipped low-tier rings and augments (but kept my armor, which doesn't affect attack power).